# jQuery $(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} ) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a click function which functioned when I had this elements hidden on page load, and then showed them later. Now I am appending those elements on click after the page has loaded, and the function of course doesn't work. I thought I would fixed the problem with `load()` function but it still doesn't work. This is the html I append on click:

```
$('#magazine-detail')[0].innerHTML = '<section id="magazine-detail" class="magazine-detail"><div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns"><div class="magazine-hero"><img id="image" src="/imagecache/cover/' + magazineImage + '" alt="' + name + '" /><div class="magazine-preview-nav"><div class="right-arrow" id="forward"><img src="/img/right-arrow-black.svg" /><p>Neste utgivelse</p></div><div class="left-arrow" id="back"><img src="/img/left-arrow-black.svg" /><p>Forrige utgivelse</p></div></div></div></div><div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns"><div class="row"><div class="small-6 columns magazine-title"><h1 id="name"></h1></div></div><p id="summary"></p><img id="issueImage" src="" alt="" /><p></p><button class="button primary expand">Kjøp abonnement - 1 måned gratis</button><button class="button secondary expand">Bla igjennom arkivet</button></div></section>';
```

There I create `#forward` and `#back` elements, for which I have functions on click in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imagesIndex = 0;
    nextImage = 0;
    loadedImages = new Array();

    function preload() {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (nextImage < images.length) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage];
                loadedImages[nextImage] = img;
                ++nextImage;
            }
        }
    }

    $('#forward').load('click', function() {
      imagesIndex++;
      preload();

      if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 1)) {
          imagesIndex = loadedImages.length - 1;
      }

      $('#image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
    });

    $('#back').load('click', function() {
        imagesIndex--;

        if (imagesIndex < 0) {
            imagesIndex = 0;
        }

        $('#image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
    });
});
```

I have tried with:

```
$(document).on('click','#forward', function() {
      console.log('entered');
      imagesIndex++;
      preload();

      if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 1)) {
          imagesIndex = loadedImages.length - 1;
      }

      $('#image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
    });

    $(document).on('click','#forward', function() {
        imagesIndex--;

        if (imagesIndex < 0) {
            imagesIndex = 0;
        }

        $('#image').attr({"src" : loadedImages[imagesIndex].src, "alt" : name});
    });
```

But nothing gets logged when I click on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#existingParent").on("click", ".child", function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write like this

```
  $(document).on('click','#forward', function() {
```

Comment: I tried it like that, but it is still not working.

Comment: you mean the function is not triggered? put a console.log in it

Comment: I put a console.log in it but nothing got logged

Comment: make sure anything does not overlay it ... give it z-index in css